# Nginx - https://www not 301 redirecting

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2

I am moving to a new domain and have set up 301 redirects on my ec2 instance.

Currently I have the following:

```
server {
   listen 80;
   server_name olddomain.co.uk;
   return 301 $scheme://www.newdomain.com$request_uri;
}
```

this works fine for [www.olddomain.co.uk](http://www.olddomain.co.uk) and olddomain.co.uk. However it does not work for https://www.olddomain.co.uk

I am wondering how I can make it so the redirect also works with https://www...

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you only redirecting HTTP (listen 80) you should add new line  for HTTPS port

```
server {
   listen 80;
   server_name olddomain.co.uk;
   return 301 $scheme://www.newdomain.com$request_uri;
}

server {
   listen 443;
   server_name olddomain.co.uk;
   return 301 $scheme://www.newdomain.com$request_uri;
}
```